# Dimensionality of inverse image of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I have a differentiable function

$f : R^m \rightarrow R^n $

with $m > n$. I also have a point $y \in f[R^m]$. Without assuming anything else about the function can I say anything about the dimensionality about the preimage of y under the function $f^{-1}[y]$?

Answer (score 1):

It's a well-known theorem (Whitney?) that **every** closed subset
of $\Bbb R^m$ can be realised as the zero set of a $C^\infty$ function
from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R$. So you can say that $f^{-1}[y]$
is closed, but nothing else.

Comment: Under what conditions would I be able to make statements about the dimensionality of $f^{-1}[y]$?

Comment: @mdornfe1 That it's a regular value, for instance, namely that $f$ is a submersion at all points of $f^{-1}[y]$.

Comment: Shark the Unkown Then what can I say about the dimensionality of $f^{-1}[y]$?

Comment: @mdornfe1 Then it is a submanifold of dimension $m-n$.

Comment: @Shark the Unknown Okay got it. Thanks!